# Styling not applied to vue web component during development

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, web-component

While developing a Vue web component, the `style` is not applied to the web component, but added to the `head` of the document. This means that the style is ignored in the shadow DOM. Here is how I wrap the web component in main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import wrap from '@vue/web-component-wrapper';
import MyWebComponent from './components/MyWebComponent';

const WrappedElement = wrap(Vue, MyWebComponent);

window.customElements.define('my-web-component', WrappedElement);
```

Again, any CSS rules inside the style tags do not take effect.

When I build for production, the styles *are* added to the web component. I use the following command to do the wrapping:

```
vue-cli-service build  --target wc --name my-web-component ./src/components/MyWebComponent.vue
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with `vue-cli-service serve`?

edit: example repo here: https://github.com/snirp/vue-web-component

edit2: I have the feeling my problem is closely related to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper/issues/12). I cannot make much sense of the workarounds, and I would value a more basic solution.

Answer (score 28):

Based on the GitHub issue you linked, the [solution](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper/issues/12#issuecomment-385141573) is to set the [`shadowMode` option in `vue-loader`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#productionmode) and `vue-style-loader`. `shadowMode` is `false` by default in a Vue CLI project, but we can tweak that in [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js).

First, we'd [inspect the Webpack config](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config) to determine which loaders to change:

```
# run at project root
vue inspect
```

The [command output](https://gist.github.com/tony19/c4f3299958ec48bbc9421258394ddd7f) reveals several loader configs with `shadowMode: false`:

```
/* config.module.rule('css') */
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  oneOf: [
    /* config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue-modules') */
    {
      resourceQuery: /module/,
      use: [
        /* config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader') */
        {
          loader: 'vue-style-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            shadowMode: false  // <---
          }
        },
        /* ... */
      ]
    },
    /* ... */
```

*full list of Webpack loader configs with `shadowMode: false`:*

```
config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader')
config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('css').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('css').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('less').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('less').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('less').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('less').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader')
config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader')
```

So, we can set `shadowMode: true` for those configs in `vue.config.js` with this snippet:

```
function enableShadowCss(config) {
  const configs = [
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader'),
    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
  ];
  configs.forEach(c => c.tap(options => {
    options.shadowMode = true;
    return options;
  }));
}

module.exports = {
  // https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced
  chainWebpack: config => {
    enableShadowCss(config);
  }
}
```

Creating `<projectroot>/vue.config.js` with the snippet above enables Shadow CSS in development mode in your project. See https://github.com/snirp/vue-web-component/pull/1.

Comment: This needs to be in Vue Documentation! I have looked far and wide for the past 2 days for this answer.

Comment: In my case, in a Web Component + Typescript setup, styles imported as JS would not inject even with the above in the vue.config.js. The only thing that finally worked was to import scss styles in component style tag as:
<style lang="scss" src="./x.scss" module></style>

Comment: Run these two commands to get a list like the one above: 1: `npx vue-cli-service inspect > config.js` — 2: `cat config.js | grep ".use('vue-style-loader')"`. Don't forget `vue-loader`.

Comment: I got error when I build the component. What node version should I use? I tried with 17,16 and 14 and I get error. 
It will be nice to add the cdn for the exact vue version on code/stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of @tony19 answer with the script that does update shadowDom to true for all components, but you don't have to list them statically.

```
function enableShadowCss(config) {
  const configs = [
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader'),
  ];

  // based on common rules returned by `vue inspect`
  const ruleSets = ['css', 'postcss', 'scss', 'sass', 'less', 'stylus'];
  const ruleNames = ['vue-modules', 'vue', 'normal-modules', 'normal'];

  ruleSets.forEach((ruleSet) => {
    if (config.module.rules.store.has(ruleSet)) {
      ruleNames.forEach((rName) => {
        if (config.module.rule(ruleSet).oneOfs.store.has(rName)) {
          if (config.module.rule(ruleSet).oneOf(rName).uses.store.has('vue-style-loader')) {
            configs.push(config.module.rule(ruleSet).oneOf(rName).use('vue-style-loader'));
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

  if (!process.env.BUILD_MODE) {
    process.env.BUILD_MODE = config.store.get('mode');
  }

  configs.forEach((c) => c.tap((options) => {
    options.shadowMode = true;
    return options;
  }));
}

// ...
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    enableShadowCss(config);
  },
}
```