# NPM Module's CSS not applied using @vue/web-component-wrapper VueJS Webcomponents

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, web-component

While developing a Vue web component, using @vue/web-component-wrapper, the styles of npm_modules are not applied. The css actually isn't loaded at all.
Here is my **main.js**:

```js
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import wrap from '@vue/web-component-wrapper';
    import App from './App.vue';
    import '@/modules/filters';
    import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
    import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all';

    const wrappedElement = wrap(Vue, App);

    window.customElements.define('hello-there', wrappedElement);
```

Before that, I had the problem, that even my normal css wasn't applied. I resolved this, by help of the answer of this question: [Styling not applied to vue web component during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431754/styling-not-applied-to-vue-web-component-during-development)

Even those imported styles in main.js:

```js
 import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

won't load at all.

First thought -> there is something wrong with the webpack css-loader/vue-style-loader

Here is my **vue.config.js** (using the workaround from the above mentioned question):

```js
function enableShadowCss(config) {
  const configs = [
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader'),
    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('css').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('postcss').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('sass').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('less').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('vue-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('vue').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('normal-modules').use('vue-style-loader'),
    config.module.rule('stylus').oneOf('normal').use('vue-style-loader'),
  ];
  configs.forEach((c) =>
    c.tap((options) => {
      options.shadowMode = true;
      return options;
    })
  );
}

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    enableShadowCss(config);
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      libraryExport: 'default',
    },
    resolve: {
      symlinks: false, 
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ya?ml$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          sideEffects: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  css: {
    extract: false,
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/styles/_variables.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

So I tried to add css-loader/vue-style-loader manually to webpack with:

```js
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    enableShadowCss(config);
    config.module
      .rule('css')
      .test(/\.css$/)
      .use('css-loader')
      .loader('css-loader')
      .end();
  },
```

maybe those styles load now, but it throws an syntax error whilst building anyways:

```sh
./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css

Syntax Error: CssSyntaxError

(1:4) /Users/.../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css Unknown word

> 1 | // style-loader: Adds some css to the DOM by adding a <style> tag
    |    ^
  2 | 
  3 | // load the styles
```

I know I know, seems obvious but those lines don't appear in the file at all. Maybe in an imported file though.

Without using the wc-wrapper everything works fine!!
Well anyways... no clue what I should try next. I am a newbie to webpack and Vue!

If anybody has an idea I would greatly appreciate it!

Cheers

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?